# Mobile Skin search different than normal skin search

Tags: php, magento, search, mobile, skin

I have a Magento setup with a mobile skin and a separate customized skin.  When I use the mobile skin and search, the same 5 results are returned.  If I search on the normal front end though, the search results work correctly.  I looked at the result.phtml file in the mobile skin dir and replaced it with one from base, but there wasn't a change in behavior.

Anyone ever encounter this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  The catalogsearch.xml in layout/ was corrupted and causing false search results in the mobile skin.  This was custom to the mobile skin so once I removed it and cleared the cache, then it used the default xml and it works now.